# How to query from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How to get all the books of a specific author from my database?

Here is a snapshot of my database, i want to get "Colson Whitehead"

[image: here is a snapshot of my database, i want to get "Colson Whitehead"]
for web development, javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all books by author Colson Whitehead, you do a query like this:

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("books").orderByChild("author").equalTo("Colson Whitehead");
query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(bookSnapshot) {
    console.log(bookSnapshot.key+": "+bookSnapshot.val());
  });
})
```

This callback will get called initially and then every time something about the books by Colson Whitehead changes. If you only want the initial call, use `once` instead of `on`.